# Flash Pro CS6 - Exporting Sprite Sheet With EaselJS JSON Data

Tags: adobe-flash, image-sprites

I've imported a png sequence into Flash Pro and have been trying to get the new sprite sheet generation feature to export JSON data in EaselJS format, but when I choose the EaselJS option from the dropdown menu, I only get a window function:

```
(function(window) {
}(window));
```

However, when I export as JSON, I do get proper JSON data.  Is this a known issue with EaselJS support in CS6, or should I be doing something differently?  I'd rather not use Zoe, the SWF to EaselJS AIR utility, because the pngs are fairly large and Zoe seems to have a maximum dimention cap for exporting sprite sheets, I get 12 of them whereas Flash Pro is able to auto detect dimentions, exporting one sprite sheet, which is great, I just need to get it to generate the EaselJS data along with it.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Having a similar issue I found these couple of resources that could be useful in this matter:

- http://www.dehats.com/drupal/node/112
- https://github.com/davidderaedt/createjs-utils

The first a blog post about the sprites generation and the second a github project for two different ways of exporting easeljs formatted spritesheets.